# Issues with comparing magnitude symbolic expressions in Pydrake

Tags: python, drake

I'm writing some code based on the potential iLQR template from the underactuated robotics course (google colab), and for my trajectory optimization problem in particular, I added collision avoidance costs as a part of the trajectory cost (because I have a three-agent system). The code is as follows:

```
eps = 1e-6
def cost_avoidance(x): # `hard coded` for 3 agents! so x must have shape (12,) and u has shape (6,)
    m = sym if x.dtype == object else np

    threshold = 0.5 #meters -> this threshold is perhaps a realistic distance 
    #at which aerodynamic interference between quadcopters start to affect each other

    pos_x1_coor = [x[0], x[1]]
    pos_x2_coor = [x[4], x[5]]
    pos_x3_coor = [x[8] , x[9]]
    
    #Euclidean distance between agent i and j
    d_12 = m.sqrt((pos_x1_coor[0]-pos_x2_coor[0]+eps)**2+(pos_x1_coor[1]-pos_x2_coor[1]+eps)**2)
    d_13 = m.sqrt((pos_x1_coor[0]-pos_x3_coor[0]+eps)**2+(pos_x3_coor[1]-pos_x3_coor[1]+eps)**2)
    d_23 = m.sqrt((pos_x2_coor[0]-pos_x3_coor[0]+eps)**2+(pos_x2_coor[1]-pos_x3_coor[1]+eps)**2)

    d_12_cost = 0
    d_13_cost = 0
    d_23_cost = 0

    if d_12 < threshold:
        d_12_cost = 10*d_12
   
    if d_23 < threshold:
        d_23_cost = 10*d_23

    if d_13 < threshold:

        d_13_cost = 10*d_13 

    return -(d_12_cost+d_13_cost+d_23_cost)

def cost_stage(x, u):
    
    c_avoid = cost_avoidance(x)
    c_trj = cost_trj(x,u)
    
    return c_avoid + c_trj


x_sym = np.array([sym.Variable("x_{}".format(i)) for i in range(3*n_x)])
u_sym = np.array([sym.Variable("u_{}".format(i)) for i in range(3*n_u)])
x = x_sym
u = u_sym

l = cost_stage(x,u)
```

The issue arises at the bottom line when i tried to compute the stage cost symbolically. The error message says

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-d3a4ccc6cac8> in <module>()
      4 u = u_sym
      5 
----> 6 l = cost_stage(x,u)
      7 #l_x = sym.Jacobian([l], x).ravel()
      8 #l_x

1 frames
<ipython-input-159-10c338807d59> in cost_stage(x, u)
      1 def cost_stage(x, u):
      2 
----> 3     c_avoid = cost_avoidance(x)
      4     c_trj = cost_trj(x,u)
      5 

<ipython-input-157-32474b2ff1aa> in cost_avoidance(x)
     19     d_23_cost = 0
     20 
---> 21     if d_12 < threshold:
     22         d_12_cost = 10*d_12
     23 

RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`. If you are trying to make a map with `Variable`, `Expression`, or `Polynomial` as keys (and then access the map in Python), please use pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict`.
```

Intuitively I know that this is due to how Pydrake handles symbolic comparison: in my avoidance cost function, I only impose a penalty when the distance between agents are below a certain threshold. I wonder how I should fix this issue?

**Edit:**
According to the error message, I should use `pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict` , it is not working:

```
if pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict(d_12) < threshold:
      d_12_cost = 10*d_12
```

Comment: May I ask why you need symbolic computation for the cost in iLQR? I suppose you need the Hessian and gradient of the cost, which you can obtain by doing automatic differentiation.

Comment: I have been using the Google colab template code from the underactuated robotics course at MIT, and in their code they used symbolic variables all the way through (I guess it's for derivation purposes), so I'm just sticking to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked carefully, but would [if_then_else](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.symbolic.html#pydrake.symbolic.if_then_else) expression resolve your problem?

```py
d_12_cost = if_then_else(d_12 < threshold, 10*d_12, 0)
```

Comment: thanks! I just tried this, but I got an error message :```TypeError: if_then_else(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (f_cond: drake::symbolic::Formula, e_then: pydrake.symbolic.Expression, e_else: pydrake.symbolic.Expression) -> pydrake.symbolic.Expression

Invoked with: True, 1.414213562373095e-05, 0```

Comment: Ah, interesting, the non-Expression overload isn't bound in pydrake yet.  For now, I guess you can use this fix only when `x.dtype == object`, and use your old code in the other cases.  I think that should resolve this exception, but your problem is probably deeper than just the syntax.  I don't think the Jacboians and such would work with conditions.

Comment: I see! Perhaps I will switch all the symbolic representations to numerical representations.  I wonder what is the equivalent numerical `Jacobian` function in Drake?